# Accessing 'training' attribute in TensorFlow functional (functional API) Model

Tags: python, tensorflow

As the title states I'm wondering how I could access the [privileged 'training' argument](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#privileged_training_argument_in_the_call_method) when I'm using the functional API.

So if I use subclassing, I can write something like:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.BN = tf.keras.Layers.BatchNormalization()
  
  def call(self,inputs, training=None):
    self.BN(inputs, training=training)
```

So I can control how my batchnorm behaves during training and prediction. But If I want to use the functional API:

```
input = tf.Input(someshape)
normalized = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(input)
tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=normalized)
```

Now I can't really set the priviledged 'training' argument for my batch_norm anymore. I love the functional API, its just really so much fun to use, but having to build around this kind of is a dealbreaker quite often. I feel like I must miss some important idea on how one would solve this here.
I'm aware that I could create a tf.Input, which could hold the 'training' argument. But this would change it from a keyord arg to some element of a list, which creates very very inconsistent code. Any smarter solution to this?

Edit: Should make it clear that I'm looking for a general idea that can be used for the 'training' arg, not just tackling the BatchNormalization in particular.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the model `model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=normalized)`, the model has not yet been built. You will need to call the build method, usually when you do everything by hand using the gradient tape, or when you first call the fit method. At that point, the weights will be initialized. Now, if you use the *fit* method or call your model `output_tensors = mymodel(input_tensors, training=True)`, or conversely if you use the *predict* method or `use output_tensors = mymodel(input_tensors, training=False)`, the training flag will be set to True or False, (which is obvious if you call the model directly).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your insights! While I understand I can still pass the training flag, the key problem is that I can't access it from any of the layers included in the funcitonal model.

Comment: Instead of the functional model, you need to create a custom Model subclass and pass the training flag to the call method, [here is an example of Model subclass](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_model_class)